# Using Selenium Alert Handler in VBA with Chrome

Tags: excel, vba, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, alert

I've placed a serial number in a box and clicked the button, and a popup alert appears saying that serial number is not found, OK to continue.

```
TagSerialBox.Clear        ' Clear the default text already in the box
On Error GoTo AlertHandler  ' Go here if serial number not found
TagSerialBox.SendKeys serial ' Enter the serial number into the box
 Dim ClickPreview As selenium.WebElement  ' This is the item displayed
 Set ClickPreview = Partssite.FindElementById("fetchlink")   ' Focus on the link
    ClickPreview.Click       ' Click the link


AlertHandler: 
    MsgBox "Serial# " & serial & " not found, need to re-enter"
driver.SwitchToAlert().Accept    ' Should send OK to the alert popup and continue.
```

This code works fine when the serial number is found, but when it isn't found, it goes to the Alert Handler as expected and

- the MsgBox works fine
- the execution fails on the "driver.SwitchToAlert().Accept" line with a Run-time error '424':   Object required.
  I can't figure out what to do from the Selenium documentation.
  Can ayone help with this?
  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try: driver.SwitchToAlert.Accept

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35495911)